# How to write "Expire in" HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to write a HOC that changes its state attribute `visible` to `false` after some time.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
const withExpire = (WrappedComponent) => 
    class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                visible: props.visible,
            };
        }

        render() {
            const expire_in = this.props.expire_in || 3000;
            if (this.state.visible) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({ visible: false });
                }, 1000);
            }
            return <WrappedComponent visible={this.state.visible} {...this.props} />;
        }
    }
```

I've checked that code inside `if (this.state.visible)` runs, but it doesn't change my `visible` attribute.

Can someone explain me what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

**SOLUTION:**

```
const withExpire = (WrappedComponent) => 
    class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                visible: props.visible,
            };
            this.timeoutID = null;
        }

        componentWillMount () {
            const expire_in = this.props.expire_in || 3000;
            if (this.state.visible) {
                this.timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({ visible: false });
                }, expire_in);
            }
        }

        componentWillUnmount () {
            if (this.timeoutID) {
                window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
            }
        }

        render () {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} visible={this.state.visible} />;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use this kind of logic in `render()`, as you don't know how many times it will fire. Try using `componentWillMount` instead, this will make it only run once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually implemented the perfect example against HOC usage. You can't be sure about what's coming in from the outside as props.

In this example the external `visible` property through `{...this.props}` overrides the `visbile={this.state.visible}` property.

A quick fix (by swapping the order of property definitions):

```
...
return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} visible={this.state.visible} />;
...
```

Also, don't forget to properly handle the Timer. You should store any timers and if still active cancel them in `componentWillUnmount`. Otherwise a still running timer in an unmounted component might cause errors thrown around.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I'm interested in why this is "the perfect example against HOC usage" and then what is the right approach to implement the behavior I want to archive. Do I then need to handle this expiring in each component individually or what?

Comment: HOCs are perfectly fine, you just have to be a bit more careful with them.